# Camaleon-CMS: How to disable media files edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, camaleon

Is there a way to disable the media items edit button? Either in the Camaleon configuration or by using a hook... In my case, the user can only upload images and use them, but cannot edit them!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the current version you can do it by adding a css style using the hook "admin_before_load".

app/apps/themes/my_theme/config/config.json

`"hooks": {
    "admin_before_load": ["my_function_admin_before_load"],
    ....
}`

app/apps/themes/my_theme/main_helper.rb

`def my_function_admin_before_load
    append_asset_content('<style>#cama_media_gallery .media_item .edit_item{display: none;}</style>')
  end`

In current development version I added two hooks "file_manager_edit_file" and "file_manager_del_file"

Regards!

Comment: Thanks @Owen Peredo Diaz , it worked by using the append_asset_content method ;)